# Using GREL function uniques() to remove duplicates

Tags: duplicates, unique, openrefine

| Name | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| Aurelia;Camila;Aurelia;Camila | Female;Female;Female;Female |

I want to remove the duplicates in these columns.

I using this formula: value.split(";").uniques().join(", ") and return me this:

| Name | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| Aurelia,Camila | Female |

But i want to return:

---

| Name | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Aurelia,Camila | Female, Female |

Comment: More context would be useful, but I'd suggest looking into "Split multi-value cells" and then dealing with things on a per-row basis, but a lot depends on what the rest of the data looks like.